# Github Action Trigger on multiple on: push: paths

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

In single repo, I want to create more than one trigger for different paths [`paths: 'frontend/**'` and `paths: 'backend/**'`] with different parameters for (same) build jobs. Following are the two workflow.

```
name: Trigger Jenkins Build [ Build-Portal ]
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
    paths: 'frontend/**'
    types: [closed]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Triggering Jenkins Build [ Build-Portal ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:
    - name: Trigger Build-Portal
      uses: actions/trigger-jenkins@develop
      with:
        ...
        job_name: "Build-Portal"
        job_params: '{"FRESH_BUILD":"True", "UI":"True", "BUILD_BRANCH":"develop", "DEPLOY_DEV":"True"}'
        ...
```

and

```
name: Trigger Jenkins Build [ Build-Portal ]
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
    paths: 'backend/**'
    types: [closed]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Triggering Jenkins Build [ Build-Portal ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:
    - name: Trigger Build-Portal
      uses: actions/trigger-jenkins@develop
      with:
        ...
        job_name: "Build-Portal"
        job_params: '{"FRESH_BUILD":"True", "API":"True", "BUILD_BRANCH":"develop", "DEPLOY_DEV":"True"}'
        ...
```

Can I combine these two in a single workflow file (`.github/workflows/`) or it need to have separate files for each ?

**Note** : `job_params` are different in for both triggers.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [github action documentation](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-positive-and-negative-patterns), it should work in the same workflow using multiple paths.

If you also use the [paths-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) you can get to the result you want with something like this:

**Example:**

```
name: Trigger Jenkins Build [ Build-Portal ]
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
    paths: 
       - 'frontend/**'
       - 'backend/**'
    types: [closed]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Triggering Jenkins Build [ Build-Portal ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:
      - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
        id: changes
        with:
           filters: |
              backend:
                - 'backend/**'
              frontend:
                - 'frontend/**'
    - name: Trigger Build-Portal FRONTEND
      # run only if some file in 'frontend' folder was changed
      if: steps.changes.outputs.frontend == 'true'
      uses: actions/trigger-jenkins@develop
      with:
        ...
        job_name: "Build-Portal"
        job_params: '{"FRESH_BUILD":"True", "UI":"True", "BUILD_BRANCH":"develop", "DEPLOY_DEV":"True"}'
        ...
     - name: Trigger Build-Portal BACKEND
      # run only if some file not 'backend' folder was changed
      if: steps.changes.outputs.backend == 'true'
      uses: actions/trigger-jenkins@develop
      with:
        ...
        job_name: "Build-Portal"
        job_params: '{"FRESH_BUILD":"True", "API":"True", "BUILD_BRANCH":"develop", "DEPLOY_DEV":"True"}'
        ...
```

Comment: `job_params` are different for both triggers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the UI and API difference in the job_params. In that case, you can use 2 jobs with an if condition different according to the path used. It is also possible to use the [paths-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter)

Comment: I updated the answer with an example using this paths-filter action

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to dorny/paths-filter; I used it to solve [a similar filtering issue](https://github.community/t/how-to-trigger-a-github-action-for-a-branch-or-changes-to-a-path/207444/2?u=theory).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason behind this complexity. Just use 2 YML files

`frontend.yml` => this is where you put path condition to match frontend path

```
on:
 push:
  branches: [ develop ]
  paths: 
   - 'frontend/**'
```

`backend.yml` => this is where you put path condition to match backend path

```
on:
 push:
  branches: [ develop ]
  paths: 
   - 'backend/**'
```

Both files will be evaluated everytime a push is done and GH will decide which flow to run.

You can always use a default yml file to run anyway whenever any change occurs outside these paths