# Trigger GitHub Actions Only for a Sub Module in a Multi Module Project

Tags: scala, sbt, github-actions

I have a multi module GitHub project which I would like to build using GitHub actions. The action script that I have written is a publish script that triggers when a tag is pushed. I need two things here that should work out, but before here is my project structure:

```
main-project:
 build.sbt
 module1:
   build.sbt
   src/main/scala/.... 
 module2:
   build.sbt
   src/main/scala/....
```

I need to have a mechanism check that does the following:

1. When I push a tag, I will trigger my workflow and I would like that my workflow is only publishing module 1 changes
2. Is there a way to git tag only module 1?

Comment: Do you really have a build.sbt in each submodule? Usually we declare submodules in the root build.sbt and that's all.

Comment: I'd also argue that if your two submodules have different lifecycles (tags, versions..) they should probably be in different repos.

Comment: To avoid some clutter. I have build.sbt files in each module.

Comment: Here is the project that I'm working on: https://github.com/open-electrons/open-electrons-templates

Comment: The project is a collection of templates like g8, some sbt plugins. I already have publish skip for the root by default. I just added it to the other modules where I do not want it to publish. So now since I'm using tags for publishing, my action gets triggered only when I push an annotated tag. So this already helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only ever want to publish `module1`, you can set `publish / skip := true` in the project settings in `build.sbt` for other modules and the root project.

Answer (score 2):

If your modules are on different paths within the same Git repository, you could use a [path-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67941131/6309).

Note that you cannot tag just a part of a repository, but, if your changes involves only that one module, you can then decide apply a (global) tag with a naming convention reflecting the nature of the change (IE only module1 or only module2).

Comment: And if you have a naming convention on the tag, you can have a GitHub action to trigger only for this tag's pattern you're interested in. Like `module1-*`