# GitHub Actions workflow path filter not working

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm testing some GitHub Actions functionality for a workflow that I want to run for the `main` branch only when there is NO change in a file named `file-name.md`. However, the workflow keeps getting triggered even though there is a change in that file. How can I make sure that this workflow won't get triggered when there is a change in the mentioned file?

Here is how my workflow looks:

```
name: 'Try path filter'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - '**'
      - '!**/file-name.md'
```

*Note: One thing I realized is that GitHub actions consider `branches` and `tags` filter combinations separately (OR fashion) rather than together (AND) fashion. [The documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-filters-to-target-specific-branches-for-pull-request-events:%7E:text=in%20a%20workflow.-,If%20you%20define%20both%20branches/branches%2Dignore%20and%20paths%2C%20the%20workflow%20will%20only%20run%20when%20both%20filters%20are%20satisfied.,-The%20branches%20and) states that you want to use both `branches` and `paths` filters when you want to only run the workflow when both filters are satisfied.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a [`paths-ignore` subtype](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-and-excluding-paths) that allows to achieve the same result:

```
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'file-name.md'
```

Is the same thing as:

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '**' 
      - '!file-name.md'
```

*Note that if other files are updated together with this one, the workflow will be triggered.*

> When all the path names match patterns in paths-ignore, the workflow will not run. If any path names do not match patterns in paths-ignore, even if some path names match the patterns, the workflow will run.

*If you want to avoid this behavior, you would need to use a custom solution, for example by using a [paths filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter). Here are some other threads about this alternative: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708306/github-actions-run-step-job-in-a-workflow-if-changes-happen-in-specific-folde/70711156#70711156), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941070/github-action-trigger-on-multiple-on-push-paths).*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with your suggestion I can't make sure that it runs only on `main`. The documentation says that in order to trigger the workflow when both filters (branch and file) one needs to use `branches/branches-ignore` and `paths` together: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-filters-to-target-specific-branches-for-pull-request-events:~:text=in%20a%20workflow.-,If%20you%20define%20both%20branches/branches%2Dignore%20and%20paths%2C%20the%20workflow%20will%20only%20run%20when%20both%20filters%20are%20satisfied.,-The%20branches%20and

Comment: After a second read, I just understood your answer. And found it on documentation "When all the path names match patterns in paths-ignore, the workflow will not run. If any path names do not match patterns in paths-ignore, even if some path names match the patterns, the workflow will run."